# Magento maintenance.flag mysteriously created, shutting Website down

Tags: magento, maintenance-mode

For some reason my Magento 1.6.2 site has gone into maintenance mode twice in the past 12 days, yet I haven't installed or updated any extensions (as far as I'm aware) during that time.  It's pretty frustrating, since I don't even realize my site is down until I hear it from a potential customer.  I can easily fix the problem by deleting the maintenance.flag that gets created in my root directory, but I want to know how to stop this from occurring.  I'd hate for my Website to go down while I'm sleeping or over the weekend, and lose out on hours-days of potential revenue.

Has anyone else encountered this issue of phantom maintenance.flags being created?  Is it possible one of my previously installed extensions is automatically updating and causing a problem?  Is there any way to disable my site going in to maintenance mode without my consent?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you also getting error log number ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be error in one of your page rendering, like your one of file might contain error and on execution of that particular page(on request by customer) it gets error and goes into maintenance mode.

If you check index.php file, you’ll notice one interesting thingy, it checks for existence of “maintenance.flag” file in store root, if it’s found your store is put into maintenance mode. Service Temporarily Unavailable page is displayed with Please try again later message.